# Teammates and Tourism Victory

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

If I'm playing Brave New World multiplayer as part of a team it appears that, unlike science, our culture and tourism are not combined.  That means the best way for the team to win a culture victory is to give all the great artists to one player, let that player build all tourism benefiting wonders and basically concentrate entirely on that player's civ, which seems like it might not be much fun for the other player(s).  Have I understood this correctly?

Edit: I've just read the question that people have marked this as a duplicate of, sounds like it's even worse - everything I've said is true, plus you need to influence your partner too, yet you can't have open borders with them!  Sounds like this isn't a good way to go in multiplayer.